# DOMContentLoaded doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to test DOMContentLoaded event, and this code doesn't work for me.

**Html**

```
<p id="tst" >Click me</p>
<p id="tst2"> Element 2 </p>
```

**Script**

```
(function(){
    var tst, tst2;

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(evt){
        tst = document.getElementById("tst");
        tst.innerText = "Element 4";
    });
})();
```

I only want to see change innerText propertie of html element.

Thanks you all.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jastertdc/h1qjqjug/

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work": the handler is never called, throws an exception, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var tst, tst2;
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(evt) {
    tst = document.getElementById("tst");
    tst.innerHTML = "Element 4";
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="tst">Click me</p>
<p id="tst2">Element 2</p>
```

`innerText` is not valid, you should use

```
tst.innerHTML = "Element 4";
```

OR

```
tst.textContent= "Element 4";
```

Comment: I tested both properties, and I can't see any changes.

Comment: `innerHTML` for insert html content in any dom ref object, and `textContent` is use for insert text only

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine. However, you messed it up in your JSFiddle Environment Setup.

On the left pane, where you select libraries and extention, you had selected `onLoad` as when you want your scripts to be executed.

Change it to `No wrap - in <body>` and it works fine.

[Here, come take a look.](https://jsfiddle.net/h1qjqjug/2/) :)

ADDENDUM::

When you select `onLoad` in the left pane, the JSFiddle's awesome generates this code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
(function(){
    var tst, tst2;
    console.log('test')
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(evt){
        tst = document.getElementById("tst");
        tst.innerText = "Element 4";
    });
})();
}//]]>
```

As you can see, there is already `window.onload` present in the file which will be executed on `DOMContentLoaded`. And inside that you were `addEventListener`ing to `DOMContentLoaded`. So by the time you attach this event handler, the event has already occured so you won't see your text changing.

`No wrap - in <body>` on the other hand, makes the awesome generate the following code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

(function(){
    var tst, tst2;
    console.log('test');
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(evt){
        tst = document.getElementById("tst");
        tst.innerText = "Element 4";
    });
})();
//]]> 

</script>
```

And so, it works. ! :)